# How to scrape a span within nested div's from google search results through beautiful soup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]I want to scrape the "Missing:" (marked as red in the image)

```
strlink= 'https://www.google.com/search?q={0}'.format(link)
            print(strlink)
            url = strlink
            reqs = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
            print(url)
            time.sleep(10)
        try:
            root = lxml.html.parse(url)
            price = root.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div//span/@text')[0]
            print(price)
        except:
            price="None"
            print(price)
```

``][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx3VI.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx3VI.jpg)

https://www.google.com/search?q=AGL%20CO%20LOCATION%2076-78%20PITT%20ST%20SYDNEY%20NSW&oq=AGL%20CO%20LOCATION%0976-78%20PITT%20ST%20%20%20%09SYDNEY%09%09NSW&aqs=chrome..69i57.414j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct response from Google server set `User-Agent` HTTP header:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.google.com/search"
params = {
    "q": "AGL CO LOCATION 76-78 PITT ST SYDNEY NSW",
    "hl": "en",
}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}
soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
)

for result in soup.select(".g"):
    print(result.h3.text)
    print("Missing: ")
    for s in result.select("s"):   # <--- print missing values here
        print(s.text, end=" ")
    print()
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
76-78 Pitt Street, Sydney NSW 2000 - Sold Other Property ...
Missing: 
AGL CO 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sold Other Property at 76-78 Pitt Street, Sydney, NSW 2000 ...
Missing: 
AGL CO 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Telstra readies $300m telephone exchange for sale - AFR
Missing: 
AGL 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Property bigwigs sign up for Telstra's Pitt St exchange auction
Missing: 
AGL NSW 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pitt Telephone Exchange - The Skyscraper Center
Missing: 
AGL CO NSW 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Telstra to sell Sydney Pitt Street Telephone Exchange with ...
Missing: 
AGL 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sydney Central - Visit Sydney Australia
Missing: 
CO 76-78 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Michael | Pitt Street, Sydney, NSW | White Pages®
Missing: 
AGL 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Media Briefs - SAGE Journals
Missing: 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, This is giving me all the Missing values on that page. I want only first Missing value. Can you please share the updated solution

Comment: @AmishaMishra You can put `break` at the end of the first for-loop. That way only first result with missing values is printed. Or if you want just first missing, you can do `first_missing = soup.select_one("s").text`